# numpy-->PIL int type issue

Tags: python, numpy, int, python-imaging-library

So I've got the x and y values of a curve that I want to plot held as float values in numpy arrays.  Now, I want to round them to the nearest int, and plot them as pixel values in an empty PIL image.
Leaving out how I actually fill my x and y vectors, here is what we're working with:

```
# create blank image    
new_img = Image.new('L', (500,500))    
pix = new_img.load()

# round to int and convert to int    
xx = np.rint(x).astype(int)    
yy = np.rint(y).astype(int)

ordered_pairs = set(zip(xx, yy))

for i in ordered_pairs:    
    pix[i[0], i[1]] = 255
```

This gives me an error message:

```
  File "makeCurves.py", line 105, in makeCurve
    pix[i[0], i[1]] = 255        
TypeError: an integer is required
```

However, this makes no sense to me since the `.astype(int)` should have cast these puppies to an integer.  If I use `pix[int(i[0]], int(i[1])]` it works, but that's gross.

Why isn't my `.astype(int)` being recognized as int by PIL?

Comment: wow Jon thanks for neatening that up for me it was giving me quite a headache.  How does one type these questions so cleanly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that your numpy arrays have type `numpy.int64` or something similar, which PIL does not understand as an `int` that it can use to index into the image.

Try this, which converts all the `numpy.int64`s to Python `int`s:

```
# round to int and convert to int    
xx = map(int, np.rint(x).astype(int)) 
yy = map(int, np.rint(y).astype(int))
```

In case you're wondering how I figured this out, I used the `type` function on a value from a numpy array:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1.3, 403.2], [1.0, 0.3]])
>>> b = np.rint(a).astype(int)
>>> b.dtype
 dtype('int64')
>>> type(b[0, 0])
 numpy.int64
>>> type(int(b[0, 0]))
 int
```

Comment: I actually knew that this was the issue.  But I wasn't content not being able to successfully cast to int for PIL.  the map solution is really nice.  you don't even need the .astype(int).  Simply:
`xx = map(int, np.rint(x))` .  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're up to in the first part of your code, but why don't you replace pix = new_img.load() using this instead:

```
# create blank image    
new_img = Image.new('L', (500,500))

pix = array(new_img) # create an array with 500 rows and 500 columns
```

And then you can follow your original code:

```
# round to int and convert to int    
xx = np.rint(x).astype(int)    
yy = np.rint(y).astype(int)

ordered_pairs = set(zip(xx, yy))

for i in ordered_pairs:    
    pix[i[0], i[1]] = 255 

Out[23]: 
array([[  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       ..., 
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: That's beautiful.  I actually just thought of this solution after posting but it doesn't answer the initial question of what's going on with the int types.
As for first part of code, the new_img.load() loads a pixel map object, which one can fill in with intensity values as if it were an array.  But I'm not sure if there's an advantage to using it over numpy, besides having to switch back from array to image in order to see the thing.

Comment: I haven't seen a use of a pixel map object, so I can't comment on that. Reading the documentation, it does seem to have some advantages http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm however as I said I haven't seen a practical application of this. As you know, i[0] is actually an integer dtype('int64').