# PIL simple gradient and TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have seen [numpy-->PIL int type issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021249/numpy-pil-int-type-issue), but it doesn't answer my question which is simpler, as it doesn't use `numpy`. Consider this example:

```
import Image
import math

img = Image.new('L', (100, 50), 'white')
a = 0.1 # factor
for x in xrange(img.size[0]):
  for y in xrange(img.size[1]):
    # val: 0 to 255; 255/2 = 127.5;
    val = int( 127.5*math.sin(a*y) + 127.5 )
    print x, y, val, type(x), type(y), type(val)
    img.putpixel((x, y), (val, val, val))
img.save('singrad.png', 'png')
```

This fails with:

```
$ python test.py 
0 0 127 <type 'int'> <type 'int'> <type 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    img.putpixel((x, y), (val, val, val))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1267, in putpixel
    return self.im.putpixel(xy, value)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I don't see what "integer is required", - given that all of the arguments to `putpixel` are reported as `<type 'int'>`?

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an Image with mode 'L' (single 8-bit pixel value), hence the value you put needs to be an int < 255. You are putting a tuple which requires the 'RGB' mode. I would think changing your code to `img.putpixl((x,y), val)` solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Bernhard - indeed, that was the problem... cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, got it: image type `'L'` is grayscale/monochrome, so it needs a single integer value per pixel, not an RGB tuple:

```
img.putpixel((x, y), val)
```

If the image was type `'RGB'` (i.e. `Image.new('RGB',...`), then the command as written works:

```
img.putpixel((x, y), (val, val, val))
```